# Why do Gargantians call Chamber "Yunboroid" or "Yunboro"?

Tags: suisei-no-gargantia

In Suisei no Gargantia's second episode, Gargantians, out of the blue, start referring to Chamber as either "Yunboroid" or "Yunboro".

Where did they get this name from? Was it some type of 'model' name or something that Led told them? Or is it something they came up with?

Either way, what exactly does it mean?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The correct romanization is probably "Yumboroid." The word is probably a portmanteau of "yumbo" and "droid."

Yumbo was a French trademark name of excavators, now [used in Japanese](http://ja.wikipedia.org/wiki/%E3%83%A6%E3%83%B3%E3%83%9C) to refer to excavators in general (much like [dumpsters](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dumpster) in America, which was the trademark name for a mobile garbage bin).